# find the total number with rank entries

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table of customers' visits and I need to create two columns the first one will contain the total number visits for each customer and the second one is for the visit rank sorted by time, for example, :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'xx','2011-10-10'],
                   [2,'xx','2010-10-10'],
                   [3,'yy','2014-10-10'],
                   [4,'yy','2013-10-10'],
                   [5,'yy','2015-10-10'],
                   [6,'zz','2009-10-10']
                  
                  ],
                  columns=['ID','Customer_ID','Visit_Date'])
```

#### expected result

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- for "Visit_Number", use `groupby` with `rank`
- for "Total_Visits", use `groupby` with `transform` by counts

---

```
g = df.groupby('Customer_ID')
df['Visit_Number'] = g['Visit_Date'].rank().astype(int)
df['Total_Visits'] = g['ID'].transform('count')
df

   ID Customer_ID  Visit_Date  Visit_Number  Total_Visits
0   1          xx  2011-10-10             2             2
1   2          xx  2010-10-10             1             2
2   3          yy  2014-10-10             2             3
3   4          yy  2013-10-10             1             3
4   5          yy  2015-10-10             3             3
5   6          zz  2009-10-10             1             1
```